# How can add/Remove tag using Box.com API

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I am using .net library of https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2 
I am able to update the description for file/folder 
Now i want to create tag information using api.

can anyone help me how can i add/remove tag?

Comment: I presume tags was not implemented in the SDK as that was not available at the time of it's creation. Unfortunately, the officially supported SDK (https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2) does not have that implemented either -- but is on the backlog. With that said, because both the SDKs are open source, you can add the endpoint following the instructions on the developer page (https://developers.box.com/docs/#files)

Answer (score 2):

To add a tag you update the array of tags on a file/folder

```
PUT /folders/<id>      {tags:["red", "lizard", "dragon"]}
```

It will add or subtract any tags that you include or omit.  So if you'd already made that call above, and wanted to remove "red", you'd do another PUT:

```
PUT /folders/<id>      {tags:["lizard", "dragon"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a script that will loop over all the files in my 'photos' folder (~3000) and return the data so I can then individually update the tags for each file, can you point me in the right direction as to how this would work?